# Navigate to a new page and display an alert box

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httpcontext, scriptmanager

I am developing an application by using ASP.Net WebForm. Once user click a button, application will navigate to a new page and prompt out a dialog box "Welcome to JackiesGame"

However, I able to navigate to new page but the alert dialog box does not display.

The following is my sample code

```
void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL(TabId), true);
    Page page2 = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page2, page2.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Insert Successfully')", true);
}
```

Comment: you have to do the registerstartup script in the new page.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan How can I do it?

Comment: Could you add a js code in new page $( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("");
});

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan Now I have to problem is I have url for new page with string. How can I convert the URL from string into PAGE so that I can RegisterStartupScript in the new page with "Globals.NavigateURL(TabId)" url

Comment: As i understand you use Globals.navigateUrl(TabId) to retrieve your navigation url, but the script should be on the page its gone load as the given example that i gave as answer. You can still use ur first line to do the redirect. But put the RegisterScript in the load of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in page 2. On the page load it will register only for the first time the page loads the script.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
    var reg = Request["Welcome"]
       if(reg != null && reg.ToString() == "yes"){
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Insert Successfully')", true);
      }
   }
}
```

All code after the redirect is getting ignored since it has to redirect to a new page. So the code never gets triggered.

**EDIT**
Added a example of how it can look further

```
void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myUrl = Globals.NavigateURL(TabId)+"?Welcome=yes";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(myUrl, true);
}
```

Comment: Your solution it works for display of Dialog box however, every time application navigate to the page, it also display of dialog box. What I want to do is in specific situation, click from cmd button only display of the dialog box.

Comment: If you want it only for specific times then you have to give some variable and read it on load. If the variable is there then show else no.

Comment: Noted, I know what to do now. Thanks a lot

Comment: I added a example of how you could do it