# How to persist a value in asp.net label after response.redirect to same URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an application which is used by another application by passing credentials in `querystring` to my application.I will take the `querystring` and do the LDAP authentication .If it is failed , i will move to my application login page to enter credentials after clearing querystrings(`Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.Url.Query, ""), false);`) from URL.But here i have to show a message to user like invalid NT credentials.I assigned the message to Session variable and then assigned to a asp.net label,but it is not working ie no warningmessage coming.
This is the code i did

```
if (AutheticateLDAP("LDAP://dc01-opsoft.corp.ae", txtUserName.Value, txtPassword.Value))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Session["val"] = "Invalid credentials,Use NT  UserId and Password";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Url.Query))
            {
                txtUserName.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
                txtPassword.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.Url.Query, ""), false);
            }
            lblMsg.Text = Session["val"].ToString();
            return;
        }
```

Here when i debug i can see that values are properly assigned to `lblMsg.Text`,but finally it disappears in UI

Comment: instead of doing a full postback use updatepanel to do partialpostback so only the label will be updated instead of a complete page reload.

Comment: label is already there inside updatepanel

Comment: Can you show some front-end code with the updatepanel and label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand you have to remain on the same page and show a error message.

The problem below is that you do a response redirect. What happens after is that you do a redirect which results in a complete page reload.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Url.Query))
{
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.Url.Query, ""), false);
}
```

With triggering the page reload assigning the `lblMsg.text` in the response before is already lost. Meaning in the new page load you have to assing the value of the label again. Unles you call the exact same method again to get to the point where the `lblMsg.Text` is being set to makethis work.

The reason you see the lblMsg.text being set is because of doing a `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace(Request.Url.Query, ""), false);`. The false means do not end the response so it finishes to execute the code in the method and after does a redirect.

The cleaner way would be to not response.redirect but just show the label with the error. if you are concerned about the querystring and wanna clean it then keep doing a redirect and use this example [how to show a message after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644824/7324631). Instead of the javascript alert you can set the 'lblMsg.text`